# Using LXML to print out individual strings from file

Tags: python, python-2.7, lxml

I am currently writing something that gets the contents of a Shopify website and prints it out into a text file in Python 2.7 using LXML. My only problem is that using LXML I have only been able to dump all of the names into an individual string instead of listing the product name and then it's URL. Currently using it on store.highsnobiety.com this is the output:

```
Sitemap Products:  ['Copper Bracelet - 3mm - Polished', 'Copper Bracelet - 5mm - Brushed', 'Copper Bracelet - 7mm - Polished', 'Highsnobiety x EARLY - Leather Pouch', u'A Bathing Ape\xae Highsnobiety 10th Anniversary Tee', 'Highsnobiety Magazine Issue 11', 'A5', 'A6', 'A7', 'A8', 'A9', 'A10', 'Highsnobiety x Stampd Snapback - New York', 'Highsnobiety x Stampd Snapback - Berlin', 'Carhartt WIP x Highsnobiety - Hooded Sweatshirt', 'Carhartt WIP x Highsnobiety - Long-Sleeve T-Shirt', 'Carhartt WIP x Highsnobiety - Sweat Pants', 'Carhartt WIP x Highsnobiety - Beanie', 'adidas Consortium x Highsnobiety UltraBOOST', 'adidas Consortium x Highsnobiety Campus 80s', 'Highsnobiety Tonal Logo Snapback - Black', 'Highsnobiety Tonal Logo Snapback - Navy', 'Highsnobiety Tonal Logo Snapback - Red', 'Highsnobiety Tonal Logo Snapback - White', 'Highsnobiety Magazine Issue 9 - Yohji Yamamoto', 'Highsnobiety Magazine Issue 10 - Kobe Bryant', 'Highsnobiety Magazine Issue 10 - Gosha Rubchinskiy', 'Ronnie Fieg x Highsnobiety x Puma RF-Blaze of Glory', 'Ronnie Fieg x Highsnobiety x Puma RF698S']


Sitemap URLs:  ['http://store.highsnobiety.com/', 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/highsnobiety-x-simon-me-copper-bracelet-3mm', 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0279/1227/products/Highsnobiety-Bracelet-II-DSC-01.jpg?v=1439215473', 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/copy-of-highsnobiety-x-simon-me-copper-bracelet-5mm', 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0279/1227/products/Highsnobiety-Bracelet-II-DSC-02.jpg?v=1439215609', 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/copy-of-copy-of-highsnobiety-x-simon-me-copper-bracelet-7mm', 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0279/1227/products/Highsnobiety-Bracelet-II-DSC-03.jpg?v=1439215704', 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/highsnobiety-x-early-leather-pouch', 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0279/1227/products/HS3755.jpg?v=1453213731', 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/a-bathing-ape-highsnobiety-10th-anniversary-tee', 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0279/1227/products/BAPE_x_Highsnobiety_10_Year_Collaboration_DSC-1390-Edit.jpg?v=1438619379', 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/highsnobiety-magazine-issue-11', 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0279/1227/products/Highsnobiety_Magazine_Issue_11_DSC-6113-Edit.jpg?v=1442837169', 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/anniversary-product-04', 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0279/1227/products/hsb-anniversary-product-6_2048x2048_53b729db-39d1-426e-9ba1-d423fb8dca87.jpeg?v=1443194927', 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/a6', 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0279/1227/products/hsb-anniversary-product-6_2048x2048_d6a8d583-8385-4af8-a918-de12282d2dfc.jpg?v=1443195496', 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/a7', 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0279/1227/products/hsb-anniversary-product-6_2048x2048_6724dbf4-6589-44ce-a1d4-adc4e1671d74.jpg?v=1443195549', 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/a8', 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0279/1227/products/hsb-anniversary-product-6_2048x2048_defa0eb3-9f4d-4a40-a034-f63ad1bec5d3.jpg?v=1443195611', 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/a9', 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0279/1227/products/hsb-anniversary-product-6_2048x2048_4f716f1f-a0cd-4fd8-9a59-f756e1c928af.jpg?v=1443195652', 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/a10', 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0279/1227/products/hsb-anniversary-product-6_2048x2048_2a8ee68a-baa8-4cc9-b79c-ab633a410caf.jpg?v=1443195786', 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/highsnobiety-x-stampd', 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0279/1227/products/Stampd_x_Highsnobiety_10_Year_Collaboration-9418-Edit.jpg?v=1447094980', 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/highsnobiety-x-stampd-snapback-berlin', 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0279/1227/products/Stampd_x_Highsnobiety_10_Year_Collaboration-9414-Edit.jpg?v=1447096537', 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/carhartt-wip-x-highsnobiety-hoodie', 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0279/1227/products/Carhartt_x_Highsnobiety_10_Year_Collaboration_DSC-9602-Edit.jpg?v=1449071573', 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/carhartt-wip-x-highsnobiety-longsleeve', 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0279/1227/products/Carhartt_x_Highsnobiety_10_Year_Collaboration_DSC-9570-Edit_94a500f4-26b5-4178-8540-3f0541a99d7b.jpg?v=1449071483', 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/copy-of-carhartt-wip-x-highsnobiety-pants', 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0279/1227/products/Carhartt_x_Highsnobiety_10_Year_Collaboration_DSC-9723-Edit.jpg?v=1449071233', 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/copy-of-copy-of-carhartt-wip-x-highsnobiety-beanie', 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0279/1227/products/Carhartt_x_Highsnobiety_10_Year_Collaboration_DSC-9758-Edit.jpg?v=1449071637', 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/adidas-consortium-x-highsnobiety-ultraboost', 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0279/1227/products/3A5A3138.jpg?v=1459441917', 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/adidas-consortium-x-highsnobiety-campus-80s', 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0279/1227/products/3A5A3142.jpg?v=1459438003', 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/highsnobiety-logo-snapback-black', 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0279/1227/products/Highsnobiety_New_Era_Hat_II_DSC_6762.jpg?v=1417004080', 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/highsnobiety-logo-snapback-navy', 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0279/1227/products/Highsnobiety_New_Era_Hat_II_DSC_6760.jpg?v=1417005003', 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/highsnobiety-logo-snapback-red', 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0279/1227/products/Highsnobiety_New_Era_Hat_II_DSC_6758.jpg?v=1417005281', 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/highsnobiety-logo-snapback-white', 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0279/1227/products/Highsnobiety_New_Era_Hat_II_DSC_6756.jpg?v=1417005420', 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/highsnobiety-magazine-issue-9-yohji-yamamoto', 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0279/1227/products/hs-magazine-09-01.jpg?v=1411400759', 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/copy-of-highsnobiety-magazine-issue-10-kobe-bryant', 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0279/1227/products/Highsnobiety_Magazine_Issue_10_DSC-0922.jpg?v=1427706331', 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/highsnobiety-magazine-issue-10-gosha-rubchinskiy', 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0279/1227/products/Highsnobiety_Magazine_Issue_10_DSC-0923.jpg?v=1427708119', 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/ronnie-fieg-x-highsnobiety-x-puma-rf-blaze-of-glory', 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0279/1227/products/Kith_x_Puma_x_Highsnobiety_10_Year_Collaboration_DSC-7841-Edit.jpg?v=1443118302', 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/copy-of-ronnie-fieg-x-highsnobiety-x-puma-rf-blaze-of-glory', 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0279/1227/products/Kith_x_Puma_x_Highsnobiety_10_Year_Collaboration_DSC-7840-Edit.jpg?v=1443178986']
```

I would like to match the product name to the URL instead, like this:

```
Product Name: Copper Bracelet - 3mm Polished
Product URL: http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/highsnobiety-x-simon-me-copper-bracelet-3mm

... and so on
```

Current code is:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from lxml import html
import requests

# Log file location, change "z://shopify_output.txt" to your location.
log = open("z:\\shopify_output.txt", "w")

# URL of Shopify website from user input (for testing, just use store.highsnobiety.com during input)
url = 'http://' + raw_input("Enter Shopify website URL (without HTTP):  ") + '/sitemap_products_1.xml'

page = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

productNames = tree.xpath('//title/text()')
productURLS = tree.xpath('//loc/text()')

print('', file = log)
print('Sitemap Products: ', productNames, file = log)
print('', file = log)

print('', file = log)
print('Sitemap URLs: ', productURLS, file = log)
print('', file = log)
```

Any suggestions on what to try?

### --------------------------------------------------------------

Current code trying to connect the two:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from lxml import html
import requests
import time
import sys

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

# Log file location, change "z://shopify_output.txt" to your location.
logFileLocation = "z:\shopify_output.txt"

log = open(logFileLocation, "w")

# URL of Shopify website from user input (for testing, just use store.highsnobiety.com during input)
url = 'http://' + raw_input("Enter Shopify website URL (without HTTP):  ") + '/sitemap_products_1.xml'

print ('Scraping! Check log file @ ' + logFileLocation + ' to see output.')
print ("!!! Also make sure to clear file every hour or so !!!")
while True :


    page = requests.get(url)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

    url_tags =  tree.xpath("//url[image]")

    data = [(e.xpath("./image/title//text()")[0], e.xpath("./loc/text()")[0]) for e in  url_tags]

    for prod, url in data :

        productURL = [e.xpath("./loc/text()")[0] for e in  url_tags]

        productPage = requests.get(productURL)
        productTree = html.fromstring(productPage.content)

        variants = productTree.xpath("//variants[@type='array']//id[@type='integer']//text()")

        print(prod, variants)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first find each individual url tag and get the loc and title elements from each of those, that way you keep the association:

```
url = 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/sitemap_products_1.xml'

page = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

# skip first url tag with no image:title
url_tags =  tree.xpath("//url[position() > 1]")

data = [(e.xpath("./image/title//text()")[0],e.xpath("./loc/text()")[0]) for e in  url_tags]
```

data:

```
[('Copper Bracelet - 3mm - Polished', 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/highsnobiety-x-simon-me-copper-bracelet-3mm'), ('Copper Bracelet - 5mm - Brushed', 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/copy-of-highsnobiety-x-simon-me-copper-bracelet-5mm'), ('Copper Bracelet - 7mm - Polished', 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/copy-of-copy-of-highsnobiety-x-simon-me-copper-bracelet-7mm'), ('Highsnobiety x EARLY - Leather Pouch', 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/highsnobiety-x-early-leather-pouch'), (u'A Bathing Ape\xae Highsnobiety 10th Anniversary Tee', 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/a-bathing-ape-highsnobiety-10th-anniversary-tee'), ('Highsnobiety Magazine Issue 11', 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/highsnobiety-magazine-issue-11'), ('A5', 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/anniversary-product-04'), ('A6', 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/a6'), ('A7', 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/a7'), ('A8', 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/a8'), ('A9', 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/a9'), ('A10', 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/a10'), ('Highsnobiety x Stampd Snapback - New York', 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/highsnobiety-x-stampd'), ('Highsnobiety x Stampd Snapback - Berlin', 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/highsnobiety-x-stampd-snapback-berlin'), ('Carhartt WIP x Highsnobiety - Hooded Sweatshirt', 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/carhartt-wip-x-highsnobiety-hoodie'), ('Carhartt WIP x Highsnobiety - Long-Sleeve T-Shirt', 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/carhartt-wip-x-highsnobiety-longsleeve'), ('Carhartt WIP x Highsnobiety - Sweat Pants', 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/copy-of-carhartt-wip-x-highsnobiety-pants'), ('Carhartt WIP x Highsnobiety - Beanie', 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/copy-of-copy-of-carhartt-wip-x-highsnobiety-beanie'), ('adidas Consortium x Highsnobiety UltraBOOST', 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/adidas-consortium-x-highsnobiety-ultraboost'), ('adidas Consortium x Highsnobiety Campus 80s', 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/adidas-consortium-x-highsnobiety-campus-80s'), ('Highsnobiety Tonal Logo Snapback - Black', 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/highsnobiety-logo-snapback-black'), ('Highsnobiety Tonal Logo Snapback - Navy', 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/highsnobiety-logo-snapback-navy'), ('Highsnobiety Tonal Logo Snapback - Red', 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/highsnobiety-logo-snapback-red'), ('Highsnobiety Tonal Logo Snapback - White', 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/highsnobiety-logo-snapback-white'), ('Highsnobiety Magazine Issue 9 - Yohji Yamamoto', 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/highsnobiety-magazine-issue-9-yohji-yamamoto'), ('Highsnobiety Magazine Issue 10 - Kobe Bryant', 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/copy-of-highsnobiety-magazine-issue-10-kobe-bryant'), ('Highsnobiety Magazine Issue 10 - Gosha Rubchinskiy', 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/highsnobiety-magazine-issue-10-gosha-rubchinskiy'), ('Ronnie Fieg x Highsnobiety x Puma RF-Blaze of Glory', 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/ronnie-fieg-x-highsnobiety-x-puma-rf-blaze-of-glory'), ('Ronnie Fieg x Highsnobiety x Puma RF698S', 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/copy-of-ronnie-fieg-x-highsnobiety-x-puma-rf-blaze-of-glory')]
```

Another problem in your code is you are pulling the first url which does not contain a `image:title` tag, so even if you zipped your lists together you would lose data and the elements would not align.

if we didn't know there was only one at the start that did not have what we wanted, we could only select *url* nodes that had an *image* child:

```
# only select url nodes that have image child
url_tags =  tree.xpath("//url[image]")
data = [(e.xpath("./image/title//text()")[0], e.xpath("./loc/text()")[0]) for e in  url_tags]
```

That will give you exactly the same output as above.

For the other url, you need to find the *variants* tag with the type=array attribute, then extract the id with `type='integer'` and pull the text from that:

```
url ="http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/adidas-consortium-x-highsnobiety-ultraboost.xml"

import requests
from lxml.html import fromstring

page = requests.get(url)
tree = fromstring(page.content)
variants = tree.xpath("//variants[@type='array']//id[@type='integer']//text()")
print(variants)
```

Output:

```
['18099668803', '18100253571', '18100253699', '18100253763', '18100253827', '18100253955', '18100254019', '18100254083', '18100254147', '18100254211', '18100254275', '18100254403']
```

So to combine the two:

```
url = 'http://store.highsnobiety.com/sitemap_products_1.xml'

page = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

# skip first url tag with no image:title
url_tags =  tree.xpath("//url[position() > 1]")

data = [(e.xpath("./image/title//text()")[0],e.xpath("./loc/text()")[0]) for e in  url_tags]

for prod, url in data:
    # add xml extension to url
    page = requests.get(url + ".xml"))
    tree = fromstring(page.content)
    variants = tree.xpath("//variants[@type='array']//id[@type='integer']//text()")
    print(prod, variants)
```

A snippet of the output:

```
Copper Bracelet - 3mm - Polished ['3723603267']
Copper Bracelet - 5mm - Brushed ['3726247811']
Copper Bracelet - 7mm - Polished ['3726253635']
Highsnobiety x EARLY - Leather Pouch ['14541472963', '14541473027', '14541473091']
A Bathing Ape® Highsnobiety 10th Anniversary Tee ['5279811715', '5765857347', '5765857411', '5765857475']
Highsnobiety Magazine Issue 11 ['7731814659', '7730944131', '7731801347', '7731821763', '7731652675', '7731695683', '7731831363', '7731791747']
A5 ['8133817731']
A6 ['8135296323']
A7 ['8135469443']
A8 ['8135518595']
A9 ['8135556035']
```

Comment: Thanks for the fantastic answer! I have one follow-up question. If I wanted to print out the size variants that are in the product page xml file (http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/highsnobiety-x-simon-me-copper-bracelet-3mm.xml), how could I take the second string from the array and then print out those? I currently have [this](http://hastebin.com/ubaqebatay.py) but it doesn't work and I know that it's probably horribly inefficient. Any suggestions?

Comment: I will add an example in a bit

Comment: @DanielYveson, are we talking `<variants type="array">` and  if so what do you want to extract exactly?

Comment: I want to extract all tags that are <id type="integer"> @padraic

Comment: So any tag that has an attribute type=integer and only in <variants type="array"> ?

Comment: Yes, to clarify further because I miswrote it the first time. I want it to find all strings in <id type="integer"> in the <variants type="array">.

Comment: You realize there is only 1?

Comment: For that specific product there is, but for others there are multiple. See: http://store.highsnobiety.com/products/adidas-consortium-x-highsnobiety-ultraboost.xml

Comment: That is a better example, do you want them in a flat list like in the answer?

Comment: Yeah that's perfect, is there a way I could combine this so that it uses the URLs from the output of the first data array?

Comment: You just need to iterate over the first list returned and pass the url to requests, then simply follow the logic in the second part. I added an example at the end, what you do in the loop completely depends on what your goal is

Comment: Still having trouble with connecting it, I'll add what I've got so far on my post. How can I get each individual URL and pass it through? I can only pass the list through and that obviously has problems. I'm new to Python sorry in advance.

Comment: We were missing the .xml extension from the url so we were visiting the webpage not the xml